# Snowflake regexp return zero rows

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got a strange scenario in Snowflake that i am not too sure how to solve.
I have some data in a column that looks like this  -

```
ID, Names
1, Google | Bing | BAU | Sale
2, BAU | Sale | Bing
3, Google | Bing
```

I am attempting to use REGEXP to pull out anyrows that match my pattern like so -

```
where Name regexp ('Google|Bing')
```

Which i was hoping would return all 3 rows - at this stage i get zero.

Appreciate any help you guys can offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT column1 
    ,regexp_count(column1, 'Google|Bing')
FROM VALUES
('Google | Bing | BAU | Sale'),
('BAU | Sale | Bing'),
('Google | Bing');
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | REGEXP_COUNT(COLUMN1, 'GOOGLE|BING') |
| --- | --- |
| Google | Bing | BAU | Sale | 2 |
| BAU | Sale | Bing | 1 |
| Google | Bing | 2 |

so the pattern matches something...

```
SELECT column1 
FROM VALUES
    ('Google | Bing | BAU | Sale'),
    ('BAU | Sale | Bing'),
    ('Google | Bing')
WHERE column1 regexp '.*(Google|Bing).*';
```

works

| COLUMN1 |
| --- |
| Google | Bing | BAU | Sale |
| BAU | Sale | Bing |
| Google | Bing |

[because](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp.html#usage-notes):

> The function implicitly anchors a pattern at both ends (i.e. '' automatically becomes '^$', and 'ABC' automatically becomes '^ABC$'). To match any string starting with ABC, the pattern would be 'ABC.*'.

Comment: Thank you wow - thats great. I was hoping the regexp itself would behave the same way as regexp_count() with the value being passed in straight eg {Google|Bing).

Comment: Encountered the same problem: RLIKE doesn't work the way it's supposed to be. Wish Snowflake can change the syntax for `REGEXP/RLIKE` ('ABC' automatically becomes '^ABC$')

Comment: I am quite sure RLIKE is not part of the ANSI standard, so there is no “supposed to”. There is inly what you are used to, and as you work on more DB’s you will see they are all a little different. It is what makes the job fun. @ChuliangXiao